# How set a defaut working directory in python?

Tags: python, directory

I would like to change the defaut working directory in python on windows. I mean the default path is `c:/users/usename` and every time you start python you need to do

```
import os
os.chdir(path)
```

to modify it.

I would like to know if there is a way to set new directory by defaut?
For exemple with **R** we can do that by editing **Rprofile** file. But for python I don't know (i don't find) if there is this type of file.

Thank you in advance

Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

Python uses environment variables of your os. Therefore you have to adjusted your %PATH% to get what you would like to do.

```py
import pathlib

current_dir = pathlib.Path()
print(current_dir.pwd)
```

output: the directory where you started your script

Comment: Thank you i will see with what you propose. Have a nice day.  Stéph

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no way of permanently changing the default working directory in Python that I am aware of.

But, there are some things you can do like:

- If you are launching Python from the start menu of Windows, `right-click` on the icon and select `more > file location`.
- Once there you can `right-click` on the shortcut and select properties. From there you should be able to define the `Start In` location.

This could be one way to change your default directory.

Hope this answer helps you.

Comment: Thank you, yes it's a solution but work only with the defaut python interpreter not in command line of windows for exemple. At the beginning I wondered if there is this solution for all (in environment variable for example, windows registry...) apparently no.